# Proffered advice for getting PHP session variables in javascript doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, php, session

When I ask for the value of this hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="theOrigin" value="<?=$_SESSION['origin'];?>">
```

all I get is

```
<?=$_SESSION['origin'];?>
```

Something wrong?

Comment: *"all I get is

<?=$_SESSION['origin'];?>"* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I think he gets the text in generated html `<input type="hidden" name="theOrigin" value="<?=$_SESSION['origin'];?>">` in output

Comment: He means exactly what he said: 'When i ask for the value.. all I get is this..'

Comment: one of those FIIK questions, if you ask me.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the open_short_tag `<?` if this in enabled you can not use the benefit of the short echo tag `(<?=)`.

Comment: *"PHP session variables in javascript doesn't work for me"* - what JS? questions like these don't deserve answers; not till we know exactly what animal we're dealing with. Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: I'm out of this loop.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because you are using incorrect Php tags.

Try this:

```
<?php ... ?>
```

So in your case the value of your element would look like:

```
value="<?php print($_SESSION['origin']); ?>"
```

Comment: No worries. I had to make a note of it, in case someone would have downvoted you. In doing so, is not my style ;-) However, the OP's question is unclear, and whether what their output is the actual unparsed session code.

Comment: Of course, thanks :) Anyway the correct tag should fix his problem.

Comment: Look at their title: *"PHP session variables in javascript doesn't work for me"*, totally unknown animal here.